# Adding style to asp.net label

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to adding style to asp.net label, but it wont work.

```
ASP.NET Mark up
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCommentText"/>

Generated from the backend: Html mark up
<span id="ctl02_ctl36_CommentText">Only the leave the comment please</span>

............................................
```

I want to add the following style to the label

```
{
 float:right;
 width:70%;
}
```

I've tried using

1. cssClass property
2. Add this `lblCommentText.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("float", "right");` to backend
3. using javascript
   `document.getElementById('<%= lblCommentText.ClientID%>').Style.display = ("float","right");`
4. and also in-line style to the element

none of them works, can someone help me out ?

Comment: `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Couple what @abhitalks said inside a `.class` and apply that class with the `CssClass` property on the `Label`.

Answer (score 24):

Labels are rendered as spans and spans are basically inline elements. You need to make it block or inline-block in order to get the float and width have effect.

```
.yourclass {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
}
```

And then simply use `cssclass`:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCommentText" CssClass="yourclass" />
```

Answer (score 16):

Inline:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCommentText" style="float:right" />
```

Using class:

```
<style>
.styleclass{
   float: left;
}

</style>

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCommentText" CssClass="styleclass" />
```

Using ID;

```
   <style>
    #ctl02_ctl36_CommentText {
       float: left;
    }

    </style>

 <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCommentText" />
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to add from code behind then use like below:

```
lblCommentText .Attributes.CssStyle.Add("float", "right");
lblCommentText.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("width", "70%");
```

If you want to add from aspx page then create a css class like:

```
.testClass{float: right;width: 70%;}
```

and assign like this:

```
asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCommentText" runat="server" Text="test data" CssClass="testClass"
```

Answer (score 0):

asp:label is being converted to span. So, you can set

span { float:left }